# How to use the condition map function in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, reactjs

I am trying to display bootstrap carousel via ajax call using react js. Ajax receives json data consisting image name, content title and some meta information of per slide what I want to inject in DOM. So, I use the `map` function to generate all slides. My problem is, for the first slide I want to add a class `active`. But I do not know how to use condition in `map()`.

In React, I have written: (in `SliderWidget` class, I have written a comment actually where I should use `active` class conditionally)

```
var HomeCarousel = React.createClass({

getInitialState: function() {
    return {
        data: []
    }
},


componentDidMount: function() {
    $.get("/api/slider", function(result) {

        this.setState({
            data: result
        });
    }.bind(this));
},


render: function() {

    return (
        <div id={"myCarousel"} className={"carousel slide"} data-ride="carousel">

            {this.state.data.map((slider, i) => <SliderWidget key = {i} data = {slider} />)}
        </div>
    );
}

});


class SliderWidget extends React.Component {
render() {
    return (

        <div className={"item active"}> // here I want to use active class for the first slide
            <img className={"first-slide"} src="images/pexels.jpeg" alt="First slide" />
            <div className={"container"}>
                <div className={"carousel-caption"}>
                    <h3>Research Indicates Breakfast is the Most Important Meal</h3>
                    <p><a className={"btn btn-primary"} href="#" role="button">Find Out More</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    );
}
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <HomeCarousel />, document.getElementById('react-home-carousel')
);
```

Answer (score 1):

The `i` in the map callback is the loop index, so pass a property accordingly:

```
this.state.data.map( (slider, i) =>
  <SliderWidget key={i} data={slider} active={i===0} />
)
```

Then in `SliderWidget`:

```
render() {
  return (
    <div className={"item" + this.props.active ? ' active' : ''}>... 
  )
}
```

Using [classnames](https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames) will make your life even easier.

Comment: It does not work directly. I have made some change but your answer gave me idea.